# get name of selected item in core-menu

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have the following code:

```
<core-menu id="selection">
    <template repeat="{{categories as category}}">
        <core-item>{{category.name}}</core-item>
    </template>
</core-menu>
```

How can I get the category name of the currently selected item?
My current approach:

```
<script>
    Polymer("my-elem", 
    {
        categories: [], // gets filled somewhere else

        selected: function() {
            return this.$.selection.selectedItem.label;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunalety *this.$.selection.selectedItem* is undefined. How to solve?

Answer (score 0):

To use `this.$.selection.selectedItem.label`, you should define your core-item as below:

```
<core-menu id="selection">
    <template repeat="{{categories as category}}">
        <core-item label="{{category.name}}"></core-item>
    </template>
</core-menu>
```

If you want to define the label (as content) as shown below:

```
<core-menu id="selection">
    <template repeat="{{categories as category}}">
        <core-item>{{category.name}}</core-item>
    </template>
</core-menu>
```

Then, you should use `this.$.selection.selectedItem.textContent` to get your selected category

Hope this help :D

Answer (score 0):

A work-around (polymer-team is working on it).
Following an example that works well for me meanhwile, if you want to give it a try.

Replace `<core-menu>` with `<core-selector>`

**HTML:**

```
<template name="Categories">

    <core-selector id="selection">
        <template repeat="{{categories as category}}">
            <core-item>{{category.name}}</core-item>
        </template>
    </core-selector>

</template>
```

**JS:**

In the "rendered" section of your overall Template, add an EventListener:

```
Template.Category.rendered = function() {

   document.querySelector('core-selector').addEventListener('core-select', function (event) {
        if(event.detail.isSelected){
            console.log(event.detail.item.textContent);
        }
    });

};
```

The `event.detail.item` is your selected `<core-item>` and `event.detail.item.textContent` should be the category name of your selected `<core-item>`.

The "if isSelected" is necessary because the EventListener gets fired on any change, i.e. also when an item gets unselected.

Though, I found out, that if you have more than 1 element of `<core-selector>` in your DOM loaded, the EventListener would only apply to the first one. Hence, maybe it's saver to get element by its id. Hence, as in your case `<core-selector id="selection">`, we would have:

```
Template.Category.rendered = function() {

   document.getElementById("selection").addEventListener('core-select', function (event) {
        if(event.detail.isSelected){
            console.log(event.detail.item.textContent);
        }
    });

};
```

Hope this helps.